# Implement a shared element transition with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, css, user-interface

I'm developing a PhoneGap/Cordova application with AngularJS. Since my target platform is Android I looked into different approaches for activity transitions. In other words; How to animate the transition between form A and form B while providing a native and intuitive user experience.

My application will be implementing the material design guidelines and I stumbled upon a transition animation called "[shared element transition](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)" which I think would work perfectly for most of my application flows.

[image: Shared Element Transition]

I actually really like this approach and was wondering about how to achieve an implementation based on Angular 1.5 which is as generic and flexible as possible and easy to use across the application.

Since I'm still new to AngularJS, I wanted to check back with the community to find a neat way to implement something along the lines of the [shared element transition](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition) or maybe get pointed to an already existing implementation.

For those wondering, I'm using Angular 1.5 and MaterializeCSS to empower my app. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this tutorial (ready made component to use as well), it animates hero elements between different views and maintains proper routes.

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/19/angular-hero-transitions.html

To summarize, the hero element has to exist between the two views being transitioned. When transitioning, the hero element is temporarily hidden in the target view till the position animation ends. If the target view is being loaded directly (refresh, bookmark), no animation takes place and the hero element is there.